# Слова "пересказать" и "воспроизвести" — синонимы?

Tags: синонимы

Помогите мне, пожалуйста, добраться до истины.
Я сказал: «Прочитанная информация усваивается лучше, если её воспроизвести», а мой собеседник меня поправил, заменив «воспроизвести» на «пересказать». Я, конечно, высказался о том, что эти слова являются синонимами, но он заявил, что в данном случае — не совсем так. А я считаю, что именно в этом случае слово «воспроизвести» подходит на роль синонима очень хорошо. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае это не точные синонимы. Воспроизвести прочитанную информацию можно самыми различными способами: переписать от руки, напечатать на пишущей машинке или компьютере, зарисовать и т. д. Конечно, всё это может помочь лучше усвоить информацию.

Answer (score 1):

«Воспроизвести» — это сказать точно, «пересказать» — сказать не очень точно. Это **НЕ** синонимы.